# How to create simple animation with transparent background?

Tags: after-effects, animation

I'd like to create basically a HUD (head up display) using simple animations.  The following are three different videos:

- animated checkmark
- animated circle
- animated underline

Each video just draws out the symbol.  I'd like transparent backgrounds so these small videos can be used in other videos for effects.

As an example, in some video, I can introduce the animated checkmark.  You'll see the checkmark next to something I want to emphasize but everything under the checkmark (in the host video) is still visible (because of transparency in the checkmark video).

How can this be done in AE?  I'm not sure how to create a checkmark that basically draws itself out.  Are there any tutorials (youtube) that show something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the animations you want to do there are achievable with masks and the `Stroke` effect.

I suggest you start to generally learn to use After Effects, these are very simple things you want to do there and you shouldn't need any tutorial once you understand the very basics of After Effects.

Comment: I understand how to create the object.  I'm not sure how to create the animation.  For example, a left to right sweep that displays a checkmark, which makes it look as though it is been drawn.

Comment: Yes, you do that with the Stroke effect, it animates a stroke along your shape. If you don't know how to animate at all in After Effects I'd suggest watching Andrew Kramers tutorials on the Basics of After Effects: http://www.videocopilot.net/basic/

Comment: You can also just use a pre drawn shape and "reveal" them along a desired path with a mask instead of drawing a mask in the desired shape and using the stroke effect.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=td3vIz_YExg.

Comment: Ah yes thats exactly what I meant.
Still, if you plan on doing more with After Effects I highly recommend the basic tutorials on videocopilot.net